# Jersey: Injection works in resource method, but not for a EJB attribute

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey

I have a custom InjectionProvider which retrieves a `User` object from the SecurityContext and makes it available. A custom `ResourceFilter` performs the HTTP Basic authentication, creates the SecurityContext and populates it with a Principal. This is based on [this suggestion](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Principal-injection-tp3945374p3945837.html).

When I access it from a resource method, it works as expected:

```
@Stateless
@Path("foo")
public class FooResource {

  @GET
  @ResourceFilters(value = {UserAuthenticationFilter.class})
  public Response get(@Context User user) {
    return Response.ok().entity(user).build();
  }
}
```

However, when I try to inject the object as an attribute/field to the EJB, exceptions get thrown, **even though** I can see in the logs that the InjectionProvider gets called:

```
@Stateless
@Path("foo")
public class FooResource {

  @Context
  private User user;

  @GET
  @ResourceFilters(value = {UserAuthenticationFilter.class})
  public Response get() {
    return Response.ok().entity(user).build();
  }
}
```

The exception is strange:

```
[#|2011-10-31T13:35:47.691+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|StandardWrapperValve[Gateway Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Gateway Servlet threw exception
javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:534)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:724)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:247)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:449)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2528)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy166.get(Unknown Source)
....
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$ComponentProcessorFactoryImpl.get(WebApplicationImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBInjectionInterceptor.get(EJBInjectionInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBInjectionInterceptor.init(EJBInjectionInterceptor.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:133)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:964)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:393)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:376)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:526)
    ... 55 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I just noticed that before the exception is thrown, an error is reported in the server.log:

```
[#|2011-10-31T15:33:01.854+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private com.skalio.bonusapp.core.User com.skalio.bonusapp.gateway.FooResource.user|#]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a scope mismatch. You are trying to inject a request-scoped thing to a bean that is not request scoped. That won't work.

Comment: Ok I understand. A resource itself is not request scoped, but the method-call obviously is. Thanks. Is there any other way though? Or would it actually be a good pattern to inject the User at each (relevant) method call?

Comment: Plain resources are request-scoped - but stateless EJB resources are not. One idea you could try is making the User object a singleton (implementing singleton injection provider) that utilizes ThreadLocals to provide the right values of it's attributes for a given context. Or you can have UserInfo object with getUser() method that returns the right user for a given thread (using ThreadLocals) and you would inject that. You can use ContainerRequestFilter to set the values of that object for a given thread and ContainerResponseFilter to clean it up after the request has been processed.